# Prompt user to enter boat details and print them

Tags: pascal

My code works perfectly fine but I was wondering if there was any better ways I could write my code like tidy it up a bit or rewrite a part of it. I want to learn how I can write my code in a better way. The code prompts the user to type the details of 3 different boats and then prints them.

```
program BoatDetails;
uses TerminalUserInput;

type 
Boat = record
    ID : integer;
    Manufacturer : string;
    Model : string;
    Registration : string;
end;

Boats = Array of Boat;

function ReadBoat(const prompt : string): Boat;
begin
    WriteLn(prompt);
    ReadBoat.ID := readInteger('Please enter the Boat ID: ');
    ReadBoat.Manufacturer := readString('Please enter the manufacturer of the Boat: ');
    ReadBoat.Model := readString('Please enter the model of the Boat: ');
    ReadBoat.Registration := readString('Please enter the registration number for the Boat: ');
end;

procedure WriteBoat(b: Boat);
begin
    WriteLn('ID - ', b.ID);
    WriteLn('Manufacturer - ', b.Manufacturer);
    WriteLn('Model - ', b.Model);   
    WriteLn('Registration - ', b.Registration);
end;

function ReadAllBoats(count: integer): Boats;
var i : integer;
begin
     SetLength(result, count);
     for i := Low(result) to High(result) do
         result[i] := readBoat('Enter Boat details');  
end;

procedure WriteAllBoats(BoatArray: Boats);
var i : integer;
begin 
    for i := Low(BoatArray) to High(BoatArray) do
        WriteBoat(BoatArray[i]);
end;

procedure Main();
     var Boats: Array of Boat;
         index: integer;
begin
    Boats := ReadAllBoats(3);
    WriteAllBoats(Boats);
end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your `program` header

  > ```pascal
  > program BoatDetails;
  > ```

  does not list `input` and `output` as `program` parameters, but you are (implicitly) making use of `input` and `output`.
  You are apparently using a Pascal dialect that *ignores* the `program` header, so it does not cause any problems for you.
  Therefore I would actually recommend *omitting it entirely*.
  For reference, in Pascal a proper `program` header would look like this:

  ```pascal
  program boatDetails(input, output);
  ```
- This design

  > ```pascal
  > procedure Main();
  >      var Boats: Array of Boat;
  >          index: integer;
  > begin
  >     Boats := ReadAllBoats(3);
  >     WriteAllBoats(Boats);
  > end;
  >
  > begin
  >     Main();
  > end.
  > ```

  is totally unnecessary.
  It is equivalent to

  ```pascal
  var Boats: Array of Boat;
      index: integer;
  begin
      Boats := ReadAllBoats(3);
      WriteAllBoats(Boats);
  end.
  ```

  Use routines as *reusable* pieces of code, or if isn’t meant to be *re*used, then at least to *structure* your code, e. g. you can limit the lifetime of a variable this way.
- Your `readBoat` `function` has the following header:

  > ```pascal
  > function ReadBoat(const prompt : string): Boat;
  > ```

  It takes one parameter.
  However, in the entire `program` you are calling `readBoat` at one place with the same *constant* string.
  Use parameters if it somehow “changes” the routine’s behavior, in other words if “the result” of the routine *depends* on the parameter, its value.
  Here I recommend to place the prompt at the call site of `readBoat`, like so:

  ```pascal
       for i := Low(result) to High(result) do
       begin
           writeLn('Enter Boat details');
           result[i] := readBoat;
       end;
  ```
- In `ReadAllBoats` you are using the implicit `result` variable your compiler provides to you.
  But in `ReadBoat` you are using Pascal-style result definition, i. e. the variable bearing the same name as of the `function` (here `ReadBoat`).
  I think it’s best to stick to *one* style.
- Last, but not least:
  Use comments.
  Maybe for this `program` it’s unnecessary, so it’s fine.
  I just noticed the lack of comments.
  At least a brief summary *at the top* of your source code file would be nice, though.